# Caffe error: no field named "net"

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I had the Caffe C++ example program working on my computer, but after recently recompiling Caffe, I've encountered this error when I try to run the program:

> [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing
>    text-format caffe.NetParameter: 2:4: Message type "caffe.NetParameter"
>    has no field named "net".
>    upgrade_proto.cpp:928] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file,
>    param) Failed to parse NetParameter file:
>    /home/jack/Desktop/beeshiny/deploy.prototxt

Am I missing something or has the syntax of the prototxt files been changed? My deploy.prototxt file (that I pass to the C++ program) looks like this:

```
# The train/test net protocol buffer definition
net: "/home/jack/Desktop/beeshiny/deploy_arch.prototxt"
# test_iter specifies how many forward passes the test should carry out.
# In the case of MNIST, we have test batch size 100 and 100 test iterations,
# covering the full 10,000 testing images.
test_iter: 100
# Carry out testing every 500 training iterations.
test_interval: 500
# The base learning rate, momentum and the weight decay of the network.
base_lr: 0.01
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
# The learning rate policy
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.0001
power: 0.75
# Display every 100 iterations
display: 100
# The maximum number of iterations
max_iter: 10000
# snapshot intermediate results
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "lenet"
# solver mode: CPU or GPU
solver_mode: CPU
```

The contents of the deploy_arch.prototxt file referenced in the prototxt file above:

```
name: "LeNet"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 1
  dim: 24
  dim: 24
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "loss"
}
```

I don't understand why this has stopped working all of a sudden, unless an update has made my prototxt file obsolete?

Comment: the error message is about `...beeshiny/deploy.prototxt` while the solver has `.../deploy_arch.prototxt` - could this be related? Can you show the first few lines of the deploy model?

Comment: Thanks so much Shai, I updated the question with the other prototxt file and made explicit which one I was passing to the C++ program.

Comment: your `deploy.prototxt` is not describing a net, but rather a **solver**. your classifier expects a net description and therefore is unable to parse the solver.

Comment: You're right, I got completely mixed up again, thank-you so much for your help and apologies for the basic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding `caffe/python` in `$PYTHONPATH`.