# caffe test error no field named "net" on testing MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, mnist

I have the same problem as [Caffe error: no field named "net"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472524/caffe-error-no-field-named-net) on testing MNIST.

Running

```
keides2@ubuntu:~/caffe$ build/tools/caffe test -model examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt 
                       -weights examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel -iterations 100
```

I get the following output:

```
 I0820 11:31:33.820005 113569 caffe.cpp:279] Use CPU. [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 2:4: Message type "caffe.NetParameter" has no field named "net".
F0820 11:31:33.844912 113569 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: examples/mnist/lenet_solver.prototxt
Check failure stack trace:
@     0x7f3f9744edaa  (unknown) 
@     0x7f3f9744ece4  (unknown) 
@     0x7f3f9744e6e6  (unknown) 
@     0x7f3f97451687  (unknown) 
@     0x7f3f977fc0c7  caffe::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie() 
@     0x7f3f97834b0f  caffe::Net<>::Net() 
@           0x407843  test() 
@           0x405f7b  main 
@     0x7f3f9645af45  (unknown) 
@           0x406677  (unknown) 
@              (nil)  (unknown)
```

`'lenet_solver.prototxt'` and `'lenet_train_test.prototxt'` are original (not modified).

And then,

```
keides2@ubuntu:~/caffe$ printenv PYTHONPATH
/home/keides2/caffe/python
```

Could you help me?

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: what is the traon_val.prototxt? I can't find it in mnist directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `caffe test` you do not need the solver file (`lenet_solver.prototxt` in your case), but rather use the net prototxt directly.
Try:

```
 build/tools/caffe test -model examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt 
                   -weights examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel -iterations 100
```

Comment: Mr. Shai, Thank you for your pointing out and formatting. It succeeded after that test.